# should we create a tag for cs.NI?

Tags: discussion, tags

We are getting questions that are in the area of computer networks like [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7748/pagerank-for-a-non-random-searcher), [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/surveys-on-network-coding) which IMHO fall under [NI - Networking and Internet Architecture](http://arxiv.org/list/cs.NI/recent). Should we create a tag for them? If yes, what should be the tag? [ni.networking-internet](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ni.networking-internet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag you propose works for me.